# DiscordJS V13 Slash Command Choices

Tags: discord.js, command, interaction, slash

So on the discordjs guide it shows that you can add choices in a slash command.
But there is no function explained on how to get the selected choice in an interaction.

Here is the example from discordjs.guide:
[image]

But there is no explanation on how to call them in interaction or the reply.
Here is the URL of the replying to slash commands
( https://discordjs.guide/interactions/replying-to-slash-commands.html)
There is no explanation whatsoever.

So how do I call choices in the interaction.
I can call sub commands like this:
[image: image here]
But just no explanation on option choices.

Does someone know how I can call choices in for example
If the option choice is enable
then send enable
if the option choice is disable
then send disable

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the chosen option with [`CommandInteraction.options`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/CommandInteraction?scrollTo=options). Depending on the type of option, you can use a different method. In the picture of the guide, they use a string option, so [`CommandInteraction.options.getString()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/CommandInteractionOptionResolver?scrollTo=getString) is used here

```js
const chosenString = interaction.options.getString("option-name")
```

If you would like all the *possible* choices, use [`CommandInteraction.command`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/CommandInteraction?scrollTo=command). This gives an `ApplicationCommand` which has the [`options`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/ApplicationCommand?scrollTo=options) property. You can get the `choices` there (from one the array elements)

```js
const choices = interaction.command.options[0].choices // get choices of first option
```